# YaHP Converter (Yet another Html to Pdf converter) reading images and css from relative path

Tags: html, css, pdf

All,

If this has been asked before, please point me in the direction where I can find a solution. Basically, I want to user [YaHP](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/) to convert my html files into PDF. My problem is that I do not know how to reference image or CSS paths. My converted PDFs will have styling applied if it is in between the style tags, but this does not solve my image problem.

I do know that there are pay solutions out there but unfortunately for my client this is not an option. Hopefully someone out there can help me out. Thanks